# Bernoilli effect on either side of a plate is not Gallilean invariant

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation, galilean-relativity

Consider the airflow above and below a horizontal plate:

[image]

Particle density either side of the plate is the same. Ignoring thermal motion, the particles above the plate move with velocity $v$ and the particles below the plate are stationary. The Bernoilli effect predicts an upwards force on the plate.

But if I choose a Gallilean relative reference frame following one of the above particles, the particles below the plate are moving with velocity $-v$ and the Bernoulli effect predicts a downwards force on the plate.

How can these situations be reconciled?

Comment: If you move with the upper particles the lower particles have still the same velocity as the plate. The Bernoulli effect is motion compared to the plate!

Comment: Will a frictionless plate still experience the Bernoulli effect? What if the plate was a spinning disc, would it experience torque?

Comment: This is a new question and has nothing to do with your first question

Comment: An answer of "the significant motion is that which is relative to the plate" is inadequate because it doesn't explain HOW that motion is significant. I'm trying to provoke a more complete answer, and guessing at what might be relevant.

Comment: did you read Bernoulli effect  in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle, it has nothing to do with friction of the plate.

Comment: Yeah I read it but didn't understand it. But if there's no friction I don't see how the velocity of the plate would have any effect on the gas particles beside it.

Comment: Yes, if there is no friction, nothing happens, so if you move a plane  thru air you will not have any effect. The picture in your first  post assumes that you blow air over the upper surface, not moving the plane.

Comment: But it's the *relative* velocity that matters, surely?

Comment: Only the relative velocity of the air above and below, not to the plate.